# ActionResult of partial makes Layout disappear

Tags: asp.net-core, partial-views

I'm trying to validate a changed password partial view in my Index page of my Manage section. Like so,

```
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
@model IndexViewModel
@{
   ViewData["Title"] = "Manage your account";
}

<div class="row settings">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <h4>Basic information</h4>
    @await Html.PartialAsync("BasicInformation", new BasicInformationViewModel(UserManager))
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <h4>Change Password</h4>
    @await Html.PartialAsync("ChangePassword", new ChangePasswordViewModel())
</div>
```

Controller code

```
    [HttpPost("ChangePassword")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return PartialView(model);
        }
        var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
        if (user != null)
        {
            var result = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(user, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                _logger.LogInformation(3, "User changed their password successfully.");
                ViewData["StatusMessage"] = TranslationService.TranslateManageMessage(_context, ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess, "Your password has been changed.");
                return PartialView();
            }
            AddErrors(result);
            return PartialView(model);
        }

        ViewData["StatusMessage"] = TranslationService.TranslateManageMessage(_context, ManageMessageId.Error, "An error has occured.");
        return PartialView();
    }
```

So when the user changes his password, the thing I actually want to happen is that the Action get completed and the statusmessage of the partialview ges updated with what happend (succes, error, etc..). So how i have implemented it now it's work as I want it to but the only thing that is bad about this setup is that this happens.

[image: Layout gone !]

My layout just disappears and I have no idea why. I thought returning a partial view would just reload the page but seems like it's not that.

Could anyone point me in the right direction ? Or give a suggestion how to do this better ?

EDIT:

ChangePassword Partial

```
@model ChangePasswordViewModel

<form asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="ChangePassword" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
<p class="text-success">@ViewData["StatusMessage"]</p>
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="OldPassword" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="OldPassword" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="OldPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="NewPassword" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="NewPassword" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="NewPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Change password</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
@section Scripts {
@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is you are initially loading the partialview inside index view on a get request, when you post to changepassword action it is not an ajax partial post it is a full post and it is not the Index action so it is not using the index view and you are returning a partialview that is not inside any other view so there is no outer view and no layout

UPDATE: since you requested in comments to show how to make it use ajax:

In your index view wrap a div with an id around the partial like this:

```
<div id="changepassword">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("ChangePassword", new ChangePasswordViewModel())
</div>
```

and you need to include [jquery unobtrusive ajax](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/blob/master/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js)
in the Scripts section which should be in the index view not in the partial

```
@section Scripts {
@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
<script src="~/path-to-jqueryajaxunobtrusive"></script>
}
```

In your ChangePassword view change like this:

```
@model ChangePasswordViewModel

<form asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="ChangePassword" method="post" class="form-horizontal"
    data-ajax="true" 
    data-ajax-method="POST" 
    data-ajax-mode="replace" 
    data-ajax-update="#changepassword">

<p class="text-success">@ViewData["StatusMessage"]</p>
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="OldPassword" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="OldPassword" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="OldPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="NewPassword" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="NewPassword" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="NewPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Change password</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

by including the jquery unobtrusive ajax script and adding the data-* attributes as shown that should wire up the form to do an ajax post and the result should update the contents of the div with the id indicated

Comment: Could u share an example of this ? Link or so ?

Comment: an example of what? I'm telling you what you are doing wrong, your post method should not return a partial view unless it is an ajax post that is only updating part of the page, your are not using ajax so you need to return View not PartialView. If you edit your question and show the content of your ChangePassword and BasicSettings views then I would have a better understanding of what you are doing and might be able to offer more help.

Comment: The way I would do it the ChangePassword would only link from index to a changepassword action with a full non partial view which would then postback to change the password and again not use a partialview. I would not put so much on one page, but if you really want to do that then you need to make the partial views do ajax postback and then the post request could return a partial view that would update a target element via ajax

Comment: I have edited my post. The basic settings partial is still empty at the moment because it's not made yet. If i have an example of the ChangePassword one, I can adapt this to the basic settings

Comment: so you want an example how to change it to use ajax?

Comment: If you would be so kind yes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice !